# Cocos2d-x Project Setup for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Thanks in advance!
I am a cocos2d-x Developer, till now I developed games only for iOS and android using cocos2d-x, now I also want to develop game for Windows Phone using cocos2d-x, but I have no idea, how to do that, So please give me some idea:

1. Which IDE we used for it?
2. How to create cocos2d-x project for windows device?
3. How we run it on windows device?
4. I am working on mac. Is it necessary to work on windows computer for developing games for windows device?

I am using cocos2d-x v3.4 now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Visual Studio 2012 or later.
2. Use the cocos script tool.  It creates a project for all the platforms:

   cocos new SuperGame -p com.me.supergame -l cpp -d somePath
3. See the [MSDN docs for deploying on windows phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
4. Probably not the answer you want to hear but I use a vm with windows installed on my mac.

If you want to get started with the Cocos Tests on windows.

- Download Cocos2d-x 3.x
- Navigate to the cocos2d-x-3.x/build folder
- Open cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln
- Right click "CppTest" or "TestCpp" (or something similar) in the solution explorer and select "Set as Startup project."
- Build and run the project. (The build will take a long time)